# How to write stand alone business logic in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Disclaimer: I am learning flutter. I am educated in pure backend programming where the most UI-like element I ever have touched was changing the color of text-prints in the terminal...

I am writing a Flutter app, and learning as I go. Previously, I tried to first write a widget tree, and then implement the business logic as I go. However, this created a few problems:

- My app is very basic UI-wise. 95% of the challenge is creating the logic, and therefore, I will spend most time there. Even hot reload is quite slow (compared to code that executes in the terminal), and my computer is lagging when running the emulator :(
- All of my code became messy, because I am not good at UI, so when I finally managed to get some UI working, I tried to "bend" the logic around that, which created hard to read logic.

To solve this, I began writing from the bottom up, starting with the lower layers where I am more comfortable and creating a good solid logic that can (future work) pass states to the UI to display it. Right now I am working on implementing functions for handling network calls to my backend, and handling the different responses from the server appropriately from the app's perspective.
To run the code, I would run it like this:
`dart run test_get_protected_resource.dart`.
The problem is that I now need to store a token in the keychain. To do that, I want to use `flutter_secure_storage`. The problem is that, that package needs the full flutter environment. I therefore tried to figure out if my code is running in "standalone dart mode" or as a flutter app, and only call flutter specific functions if it is running as a flutter app, but I did not get that to work. Right now, I feel like I am digging myself a hole, doing something strange that should not be done, so therefore, I want to ask for best practises.

My main problem is that I want to build the logic, and just use print statements or similar for now, and work with UI later. How can I do that, within the "context" of my flutter app so that I can use flutter specific libraries? Such as storing to keychain, using cubits etc. I will have to call various functions with various variables repeatedly, and therefore, a quick execution time is important. What is the best practises in this case? How are flutter apps normally built, widgets first, then logic? Logic first then widgets? I try to build my app in layers that are as separated as possible. I understand that I will probably have to run this in an emulator, but how can I make a blank app that just calls the different functions with different variables easily that I can iterate upon?